# How should images be aligned within a blog post?

Tags: text, images, alignment

**Is there a general rule regarding alignment of relatively narrow images within single-column online text, like blog posts?**

Consider a blog post featuring column of text in which images occasionally appear. The images are generally narrower than the text itself (anywhere from, say, 20% to 70%-80%), and they're usually aligned to the left or to the center (in Left-To-Right alphabets).

I find centered images more aesthetically pleasing than left-aligned ones, but I wonder if there's a general convention about it, and whether the answer differs on any other factors (like article size or font type).

**Update** - following the comments, I'm definitely not trying to start an opinion debate here, just to learn whether there is a standard / common wisdom / rule of thumb except for personal aesthetic sense.

Comment: Any answers to this will be purely opinion. There is no standard and it depends on any number of things. It is a pure design decision.

Comment: @CAI Your comment is a pretty valid answer. I'm not trying to start an opinion war here, just to know whether there's an convention.

Comment: That's fair enough. Subjective questions aren't strictly off-topic but they're not a great fit for the Q&A format. I don't think it's a terrible question in essence, but I think needs more context. Images and text in a blog post could be literally anything. Is the image a landscape photograph, a profile picture, a vector graphic, icon...

Comment: @CAI Fair enough; updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no established conventions. If you like centred images and they work with your content, use centred images.

It's that simple :)

Side note, a *general rule of thumb for an "average"* I use is to keep images between 50% to 100% the width of your content, any smaller and it might look a little odd. Of course, this like all design, is dependant on the that actual content you have.

Comment: I don't think the 50-100% rule is something you can say without knowing what the images are or the context. There are plenty of situations where you'd want images smaller than that.

Comment: @CAI good point, edited